# Functions and looping

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have started to create a program involving a function called def grow_bacteria.
The program involved getting input from a user for estimated bacterial growth over time.
It asks:

- a generation time (how long it takes the bacteria to produce a new generation)
- the starting number of bacteria
- the total length of time the bacteria will be allowed to reproduce

---

- The function will require three arguments:

  - generation time,
  - starting number of bacteria,
  - and total time
- The function will return the final number of bacteria

So, i am having trouble with putting it into the function grow_bacteria, as well as creating the for loop.

- the number of times the for loop will loop, will be figured out by dividing the total length of time by the generation time (to find out how many generations)

  1. you will have to use int() to change the result of the division into a number useable to control the for loop
  2. alternatively you can use floor division

each time it loops, print out the current number of bacteria (then when the function is done it returns the final value). The calculation uses the formula b=B×2^n where:

```
b is the total number of bacteria
B is the starting number of bacteria
n is the generation
```

I have written out the whole assignment above. This is what I have so far;

```
import math

def grow_bacteria (b, s, t):
result = b * 2 ** (t//2)

b = int(input('How long does it take the bacteria to produce a new generation '))
s = int(input('What is the starting number of bacteria? ' ))
t = int(input('How much time will we wait for it to reproduce (minutes)? '))
r = b * 2 ** (t//2)
print ('After',t,'minutes(s) we would have',r,' Bacterias')
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything, which is actually fine because you don't ever call it. You need to double check your indentation here: it is difficult to tell which lines are part of the function `grow_bacteria`.  You're right that you'll need a `for` loop.  `for minute in range(t):` would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

```
def grow(gen_time, pop, time):
    steps = time // gen_time
    print("Start with a population of {}".format(pop))
    for n in range(1, steps+1):
        print("At T+{:>3}, we have a population of {}".format(n*gen_time, pop*(2**n)))

grow(1, 2, 3)
```

prints

```
Start with a population of 2
At T+  1, we have a population of 4
At T+  2, we have a population of 8
At T+  3, we have a population of 16
```